# Сумма элементов главной диагонали

Tags: javascript

Есть стандартная задача по нахождению суммы элементов главной диагонали. Решаю таким образом:

Способ 1)

```
var numbers = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
  [10,11,12]
];

function sum() {
  return numbers.reduce((outerTotal,row,outerIndex) =>
    outerTotal + row.reduce((innerTotal,element,innerIndex) =>
      innerIndex===outerIndex ? innerTotal + element : innerTotal
      ,0)
    ,0);
}
var result = sum();
console.log(result);
```

Но хочется упростить решение. Поэтому был придуман другой способ, который имеет синтаксическую ошибку. Как ее можно исправить?

Способ 2)

```
function sum(){
  numbers.reduce((total,row,outerIndex) => {
    console.log(total);
    console.log(...row.filter((element, innerIndex) => outerIndex === innerIndex));      //1 5 9
    //return ...row.filter((element, innerIndex) => outerIndex === innerIndex) + total;  //синтаксическая ошибка
  },0);
}
```

Comment: И зачем вообще нужен внутренний цикл? Можно же просто брать элемент по индексу.

Answer (score 3):

не слишком ли усложняете решение?

```js
var numbers = [
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6],
  [7,8,9],
  [10,11,12]
];


var sum = numbers.reduce((t,c, idx) => t+ (c[idx] || 0) , 0);

console.log(sum);
```